# Trigger code in para/begin hook for a precise paragraph

Tags: header-footer, expl3, paragraphs, hooks, everypar

I made a simple system of multiple levels paragraph counters using the `para/begin` hook:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{expl3}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\makeatletter
\ExplSyntaxOn

\int_gzero_new:N \g__mypkg_max_depth_int
%\int_gzero_new:N \g__mypkg_debug_count_int

\AddToHook { para/begin }
  {
    \int_gincr:N \g__mypkg_debug_count_int
    \int_compare:nNnTF { \g__mypkg_max_depth_int } > { 0 }
      {
        %\textsuperscript { [ \int_to_arabic:n { \g__mypkg_debug_count_int } ] }
        \textbf
          {
            \int_step_inline:nnn { 1 } { \g__mypkg_max_depth_int }
              { \arabic { mypkg@ \int_to_roman:n {#1} } . }
          }
        \int_gzero:N \g__mypkg_max_depth_int
      }
      {
        %\textsuperscript { \int_to_arabic:n { \g__mypkg_debug_count_int } }
      }
  }

\int_step_inline:nnn { 1 } { 3 }
  {
    \int_compare:nNnTF {#1} > {1}
      {
        \newcounter { mypkg@ \int_to_roman:n {#1} }
          [ mypkg@ \int_to_roman:n { \int_eval:n { #1 - 1 } } ]
      }
      { \newcounter { mypkg@ \int_to_roman:n {#1} } }

    \exp_args:Nc \NewDocumentCommand { mycmd \int_to_roman:n {#1} } {}
      {
        \stepcounter { mypkg@ \int_to_roman:n {#1} }
        \int_gset:Nn \g__mypkg_max_depth_int
          { \int_max:nn {#1} { \g__mypkg_max_depth_int } }
        \tex_ignorespaces:D
      }
  }

\ExplSyntaxOff
\makeatother

\pagestyle{fancy}

\begin{document}

\mycmdi \lipsum[2]

\mycmdi \mycmdii \lipsum[2]

\mycmdii \lipsum[2]

\mycmdi \lipsum[2]

\mycmdii \lipsum[2]

\mycmdii \lipsum[2]

This is a test

\mycmdi \mycmdii \mycmdiii \lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

It works quite well:

[image: Example of working paragraph numbering]

However, when the second paragraph of a page contains a counter command, the counter is printed by the `para/begin` hook in the header of the previous page:

[image: Error output]

By commenting out the debug commands in the MWE, one can see that the `para/begin` hook code meant to be executed on second paragraph of the page is instead run on the header while the `\g__mypkg_max_depth_int` has already been set to `1`.

Is there a way to ensure that the hook will only run on the "good" paragraph?

Comment: The hook will run everytime a paragraph is triggered in this case by fancyhdr. You need to find a way to start it and stop it in unsuitable paragraphs.

Comment: @yannisl The `\g__mypkg_max_depth_int` variable is supposed to do that: First, it is only increased by `\mycmdi`/`\mycmdii`/`\mycmdiii`. Then, the hook only display the counter when  `\g__mypkg_max_depth_int` is $> 0$, and immediately resets it to $0$.
I don't know how to ensure that the hook is not run on the header **between** the `\mycmdi/ii/iii` call and the paragraph just after it. Maybe I could add a hack to detect when the hook is run on a header paragraph, but I think that it wouldn't solve the underlying problem.

Comment: You can hook at ps@fancy  or whatever is used there and add a marker say a acounter=999  and check for that before you insert your hook's contents. You will have the same problem everywhere that a par is activated.  Or better write your own \ps@myfancy page header. Probably a better way.

Answer (score 1):

Just add a boolean that indicates if you are in text, and set that to false in the `fancyhdr` headers and footers. `fancyhdr` has a command `fancyhfinit` where you can put code like this. If you set the boolean locally in `fancyhdr` it will automatically be reset to true when you leave the header/footer.

```
\bool_new:N \g__mypkg_in_text
\bool_set_true:N \g__mypkg_in_text
...
\ExplSyntaxOn
\fancyhfinit{\bool_set_false:N \g__mypkg_in_text}
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

Then in the hook just do your count stuff only when the boolean is set.

```
\bool_if:NTF \g__mypkg_in_text
{
 ... your original code
}
{}
```

The whole code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{expl3}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\makeatletter
\ExplSyntaxOn

\int_gzero_new:N \g__mypkg_max_depth_int
\int_gzero_new:N \g__mypkg_debug_count_int
\bool_new:N \g__mypkg_in_text
\bool_set_true:N \g__mypkg_in_text

\AddToHook { para/begin }
  {
    \int_gincr:N \g__mypkg_debug_count_int
    \bool_if:NTF \g__mypkg_in_text 
    {
      \int_compare:nNnTF { \g__mypkg_max_depth_int } > { 0 }
        {
          \textsuperscript { [ \int_to_arabic:n { \g__mypkg_debug_count_int } ] }
          \textbf
            {
              \int_step_inline:nnn { 1 } { \g__mypkg_max_depth_int }
                { \arabic { mypkg@ \int_to_roman:n {#1} } . }
            }
          \int_gzero:N \g__mypkg_max_depth_int
        }
        {
          \textsuperscript { \int_to_arabic:n { \g__mypkg_debug_count_int } }
        }
    }
    {}
}

\int_step_inline:nnn { 1 } { 3 }
  {
    \int_compare:nNnTF {#1} > {1}
      {
        \newcounter { mypkg@ \int_to_roman:n {#1} }
          [ mypkg@ \int_to_roman:n { \int_eval:n { #1 - 1 } } ]
      }
      { \newcounter { mypkg@ \int_to_roman:n {#1} } }

    \exp_args:Nc \NewDocumentCommand { mycmd \int_to_roman:n {#1} } {}
      {
        \stepcounter { mypkg@ \int_to_roman:n {#1} }
        \int_gset:Nn \g__mypkg_max_depth_int
          { \int_max:nn {#1} { \g__mypkg_max_depth_int } }
        \tex_ignorespaces:D
      }
  }

\ExplSyntaxOff
\makeatother

\pagestyle{fancy}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\fancyhfinit{\bool_set_false:N \g__mypkg_in_text}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\fancyhead[L]{Test Header}

\begin{document}

\mycmdi \lipsum[2]

\mycmdi \mycmdii \lipsum[2]

\mycmdii \lipsum[2]

\mycmdi \lipsum[2]

\mycmdii \lipsum[2]

\mycmdii \lipsum[2]

This is a test

\mycmdi \mycmdii \mycmdiii \lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

[image]